# R on JSON, nested triks

Tags: json, r

Can you advise me how I can read the following .json and extract just certain fields like in sample below? I need to paste actual content of file separately. I tried to feed it into `fromJSON()` and sink but it failed, b'z special chars(?).  This is my test file:

```
{"batch_date": "2015-05",  "name": "Jeff Macronsh", "cust_cid": "001555", "clients": ["111112222", "1324132531", "1235325", "1324324321"], "fans": 2319, "rewards": 3.75, "type": "dealer", "bonuses": {"suka": 13, "plain": 4, "writer": 1, "maxima": 1, "more": 1, "prima": 5}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-07",  "name": "NWest", "cust_cid": "332224", "clients": ["093485734250"], "fans": 1, "rewards": 4.5, "type": "dealer", "bonuses": {"note": 12, "suv": 10, "prima": 1}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-11",  "name": "Muhhamed Karne", "cust_cid": "234566000",  "bonuses": {"profile": 5, "suv": 52, "cute": 1, "plain": 43, "bbb": 35, "note": 33, "photos": 3, "maxima": 56, "more": 12, "prima": 151}, "lexus": [2013, 2014]}
{"batch_date": "2013-11",  "name": "West", "cust_cid": "4567465800",  "bonuses": {"plain": 1, "maxima": 1, "more": 2, "photos": 1, "suv": 1}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-02",  "name": "Jake", "cust_cid": "6467889000",  "bonuses": {"cute": 1, "suv": 30, "plain": 43, "writer": 38, "note": 16, "photos": 2, "maxima": 33, "prima": 39, "more": 5}, "lexus": [2012, 2014, 2015]}
{"batch_date": "2014-11",  "name": "Michelle Mow", "cust_cid": "345653477",  "bonuses": {"maxima": 1, "write": 15, "platinum": 33}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2015-07",  "name": "NWest", "cust_cid": "332224", "clients": ["093485734250", "4313124324"],  "bonuses": {"note": 12, "suv": 90, "prima": 1}, "lexus": []}
```

I want to extract just

```
name     cust_id   suv   
NWest    332224     90
```

I tried to use this code but get only first row. How I can all of them in my case 6 of 7 (one doesn't have suv)?

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "test.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(file= json_file)

a <- c(json_data$name, "suv", json_data$cust_cid, json_data$bonuses$suka)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a number of steps:
s 
First, lapply from JSON to each line.
Then, put out most variables which are simple values
Then pull out bonuses, which are subdataframes, and merge them in.

A small extra section for clients, just for kicks.

Then just select the variables you want.
a

```
library(rjson)
library(rlist)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

list_structure = 
  "test.json" %>%
  readLines %>%
  lapply(fromJSON)

transaction = 
  list_structure %>%
  lapply(. %>% 
           list.remove(c("bonuses", "lexus", "clients")) %>%
           as.data.frame) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>%
  full_join(
    list_structure %>%
      lapply(. %>% 
               use_series(bonuses) %>%
               as.data.frame) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = "ID"))

clients = 
  list_structure %>%
  setNames(seq_along(.)) %>%
  lapply(. %>% use_series(clients) ) %>%
  Filter(. %>% is.null %>%`!`, .) %>%
  lapply(. %>% {data_frame(client = .)}) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>%
  mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID))


result = 
  transaction %>%
  select(name, cust_cid, suv) %>%
  filter(!is.na(suv))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Richard! Wow,  it's my first experience with json, happend to be quite complicated.  Best.Mario

Comment: Sorry, Richard  how json_string need to be defined?

Comment: I had pasted your data as a string into my program. I've updated the code so it inputs from your text.json file.

Comment: List structures like JSON are really antithetical to R's dataframe framework.