# R how to subset .json file (like flat) ,

Tags: json, r

all
I have process to flatten .json file and I used logic simular to this [logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006371/r-on-json-nested-triks/33006989#33006989) . On my real data I have 2.5 Gigs of them, so after running it for 3hrs, I decided to cancel it and filter input, as I need only part of it (~5%), let say I want to bring all raws where name = NWest.

When I do simple readLines R give me some new structure (for me-)>
 `Named Char[1:88888]`, 
I tried to assign name to it but no sucess, how to achive this?
I" bit new to R/Json so appreciate your leads, I feel that R should have something for this, how I can bring raws like '%NWest%'

```
fileName = "test.json"    
con = file(fileName, open="r")
line = readLines(con) 
names(line)
str()
names(line) <- "colx"
```

this is my input: I learned that R in subset should refer to column, but what do it if there no columns?

```
{"batch_date": "2015-05",  "name": "Jeff Macronsh", "cust_cid": "001555", "clients": ["111112222", "1324132531", "1235325", "1324324321"], "fans": 2319, "rewards": 3.75, "type": "dealer", "bonuses": {"suka": 13, "plain": 4, "writer": 1, "maxima": 1, "more": 1, "prima": 5}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-07",  "name": "NWest", "cust_cid": "332224", "clients": ["093485734250"], "fans": 1, "rewards": 4.5, "type": "dealer", "bonuses": {"note": 12, "suv": 10, "prima": 1}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-11",  "name": "Muhhamed Karne", "cust_cid": "234566000",  "bonuses": {"profile": 5, "suv": 52, "cute": 1, "plain": 43, "bbb": 35, "note": 33, "photos": 3, "maxima": 56, "more": 12, "prima": 151}, "lexus": [2013, 2014]}
{"batch_date": "2013-11",  "name": "West", "cust_cid": "4567465800",  "bonuses": {"plain": 1, "maxima": 1, "more": 2, "photos": 1, "suv": 1}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2014-02",  "name": "Jake", "cust_cid": "6467889000",  "bonuses": {"cute": 1, "suv": 30, "plain": 43, "writer": 38, "note": 16, "photos": 2, "maxima": 33, "prima": 39, "more": 5}, "lexus": [2012, 2014, 2015]}
{"batch_date": "2014-11",  "name": "Michelle Mow", "cust_cid": "345653477",  "bonuses": {"maxima": 1, "write": 15, "platinum": 33}, "lexus": []}
{"batch_date": "2015-07",  "name": "NWest", "cust_cid": "332224", "clients": ["093485734250", "4313124324"],  "bonuses": {"note": 12, "suv": 90, "prima": 1}, "lexus": []}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of selecting a subset of lines from a large file.  This will read in a portion of the input (in this case 20 lines for the example, but make it larger for your file) since I don't know how much memory you have on your system.  This will create a temporary file with the subset that you can how process.

```
> # subset a large file by reading a small number of lines, finding a 
> # match and then writing to a new file.  this assumes that each line
> # is a complete json set.
> n <- 20  # number of lines -- make large for your 2.5GB file
> output_file <- tempfile()  # output file
> output <- file(output_file, 'wt')  # text file on output
> input_file <- '/temp/json.txt'  # my input file of your data (2400 lines)
> input <- file(input_file, 'rt')
> repeat{
+     lines <- readLines(input, n = n)
+     if (length(lines) == 0L) break  # exit if done
+     # find matching lines
+     mch <- grep('"name": "NWest"', lines)  # see if any matches
+     if (length(mch) == 0L) next  # no match, read next set
+     writeLines(lines[mch], output)  # write out lines that match
+ }
> close(output)
> # show sizes of the files to show that output is a subset of input
> file.info(input_file)
                 size isdir mode               mtime               ctime               atime exe
/temp/json.txt 503360 FALSE  666 2015-10-11 18:00:02 2015-10-11 18:00:02 2015-10-11 18:00:02  no
> file.info(output_file)
                                                                         size isdir mode               mtime
C:\\Users\\jh52822\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpuc6YDS\\file25b81f2f1700 131648 FALSE  666 2015-10-11 18:15:16
                                                                                     ctime               atime
C:\\Users\\jh52822\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpuc6YDS\\file25b81f2f1700 2015-10-11 18:15:15 2015-10-11 18:15:15
                                                                       exe
C:\\Users\\jh52822\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpuc6YDS\\file25b81f2f1700  no
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `jqr` https://github.com/ropensci/jqr - an R client wrapping `jq` (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - also worth trying `jq` in your shell outside of R - we haven't tested `jqr` on very big data, so hopefully it works. It should because it calls the jq C code.  If it's too big to read in to R, using from shell would be better